# how to get value from source code using calabash iOS

Tags: ios, calabash

I am using calabash cucumber to test my IOS application. The issue is for doing validations and some other operations.  I need to get value from the source code. Is it possible? If so, how?  Please help me. I have gone through different documentations, but I did not get a proper answer.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be specific. What operations are you referring to ? What values of what source code?

Comment: i need to get some boolean values from source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can using the calabash-ios `query` language to call selectors on `UIView` and its subclasses.

If you have any experience with calabash-ios you probably have been using this feature without realizing it.

```
# calls the 'text' selector on the labels that match the query
query("label marked:'product description'", :text)
```

To see if a button is enabled, you could do the following:

```
# NB the property is 'enabled', but the selector is 'isEnabled
query("button marked:'ask for help'", :isEnabled")
```

This is described on the calabash-ios wiki:

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/03.5-Calabash-iOS-Ruby-API
https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/05-Query-syntax

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set custom attributes then one way to do it is to subclass a UI element (such as UIButton and then you can create a property which you can then access like so:

ExampleButton.h:

```
@interface ExampleButton : UIButton
{
  BOOL doingSomething;
}

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isDoingSomething;
```

ExampleButton.m

```
#import "ExampleButton.h"

@implementation ExampleButton

... //code possibly here

- (BOOL)isDoingSomething
{
  return doingSomething;
}

... //more code possibley here
```

and then you would have other code that sets doingSomething.

By the way I've only just started out in iOS and Calabash testing so I my objective C is rusty, but I think you can also not have the `doingSomething` Bool and just have `@synthesize isDoingSomething` which you can then get and set on the property directly (`self.isDoingSomething = true;` etc).

In calabash your query would look like this then:

```
query("view:'ExampleButton' isDoingSomething:1")
```

or

```
query("view:'ExampleButton' isDoingSomething:0")
```

to see if the property is true or false respectively.

This is probably not the only way to do it (it probably isn't even the easiest way to do it but it works).